# Can I pass java options to protoc on the command line?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, protoc

I have some input files that contain protobuf data, with a corresponding `.proto` definition. For the sake of a minimal example (taken from [here](https://www.baeldung.com/google-protocol-buffer)), assume this .proto file looks like

```
message Person {
    required string name = 1;
}
```

According to every example I can find on the net, I have to specify my java package and class names in the .proto file itself, amending it with

```
option java_package = "com.example.protobuf";
option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos";
```

The problem is - if I do that, I'll have to change my `.proto` file every time the vendor updates their definition, and of course the vendor doesn't want to add those options to their version, because a) they're not using java and b) different customers may have different requirements as to the package/class names.

So what I'd like to do is to not have those options in the `.proto` file, and give them on the command line to `protoc` in a way similar to this:

`protoc --java_out=. --option java_package="com.example.protobuf" --option java_outer_classname="AddressBookProtos" message.proto`

but I can't find any documentation if this is possible at all or which syntax to use.

So, is it possible to pass options to `protoc` in a similar way?

Comment: You might be able use import, i.e. create a file `myAddressBook.proto` containing `option java_package = "com.example.protobuf"; option java_outer_classname = "AddressBookProtos"; import "vendorAddressBook.proto";` (I have not tried this)

Comment: @tgdavies: No, that's not what imports in protobuf do.

Comment: @JonSkeet So you'd have to be using the `AddressBook` type in another type you defined in your own file?

Comment: @tgdavies: Yes. But it wouldn't change the package or outer classname for anything in the imported proto.

Comment: The producer of the protos **should** include `option` for the languages that their users may need. Google does this for its services. A challenge is that `option` applies to packages and `protoc` generally compiles multiple packages requiring a way to specify multiple `xxx_out` and `xxx_opt`. That said, it's reasonable to want to be able to override these with `protoc` and take the hit when you can't update the proto sources (file feedback) or you'll have to duplicate the proto sources and amend as you're doing

Comment: Is there a solution to this problem? For C#, the existing `--csharp_opt=base_namespace=`<some Prefix of the `option csharp_namespace="My.Example.Namespace"`> is just a painful solution given it assumes you even have a namespace. I feel like a caveman editing my vendor provided protoc files to add an csharp_namespace.